# How to use Gson.getAdapter(Class<?>) and TypeAdapter.write correctly with generics?

Tags: java, generics, gson

I have the following code which has only two warnings.

```
Gson gson = ...
JsonWriter = ...
Serializable value = ...
TypeAdapter adapter = gson.getAdapter(value.getClass());
adapter.write(out, value);
```

IntelliJ suggest me for the two last lines:

`Raw use of parameterized class 'TypeAdapter'`

and

`Unchecked call to 'write(JsonWriter, T)' as a member of raw type 'com.google.gson.TypeAdapter'`

I'd like to get rid of these warnings but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried the following:

```
TypeAdapter<Serializable> adapter = gson.getAdapter(value.getClass());
adapter.write(out, value);
```

Which results in an error (`Incompatible equality constraint: Serializable and capture of ? extends Serializable`).

So I've tried this but this is erroneous, too.

```
TypeAdapter<? extends Serializable> adapter = gson.getAdapter(value.getClass());
adapter.write(out, value);
```

Error is now: `Required type: capture of ? extends Serializable  Provided: Serializable`.

What can I do about it? I just hope that omitting the Generics is not the only solution to get the code running?

Comment: You definitely want to use the TypeAdapter explicitly? Commonly they are registered and then used internally by Gson.

Comment: Actually I stumpled on this code in our project. I think this code has its value but I only want to know if the above code warnings can be somehow eliminated. We probably can abstract the description of the problem to be not bound to the Gson topic.

Comment: You have to extract the `getClass()` result to a typed variable. Something like this: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final Class<? super Serializable> clazz = (Class<? super Serializable>) value.getClass(); final TypeAdapter<? super Serializable> adapter = gson.getAdapter(clazz); adapter.write(out, value);`. Not sure how fine `Class<? super Serializable>` is though.